# Does viewport meta tag work in HTML 4.01?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport, html4

I am working on a project where they have created web pages in HTML4.01 and now they want the pages should be supported with two new tracking handheld devices.

I have added `viewport` meta tag and wrote media queries for the specific devices. However, the codes are not making any changes to them. So what would be the alternative way to apply the media queries and fit to device?

```
<!-- Added the meta tage in head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c-rt.tld" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:if test="${sessionScope.IEVERSION == '6.5'}">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</c:if>
<c:if test="${sessionScope.IEVERSION =='6.0'}">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</c:if>
<html>
<HEAD>
<c:if test="${sessionScope.IEVERSION == '6.5'}">
<meta name="mobileoptimized" content="225">  


</c:if>

<TITLE><bean:message key="lbl.eporthh.common.title"/>-<bean:message key="lbl.eporthh.common.home"/> </TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/corporate/vehicles/css/<c:out value="${homeActionForm.theme}"/>" type="text/css">
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON"
       HREF="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/corporate/vehicles/images/.ico">

</HEAD>

<BODY topmargin="20%" leftmargin="0" bottommargin="5%" rightmargin="0"
    marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  style="width:device-width;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">


<html:form action="/hh" method="post" >

<TABLE  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="#E1E1F0" >
    <TR class="datextHeading1">
        <TD align="left" ><bean:message key="lbl.eporthh.common.home"/></TD>
        <TD align="right" align="left"  colspan="2" class="datext4">&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <%=(String)session.getAttribute("USER_ID") %> : <%=(String)session.getAttribute("PORTID") %>&nbsp;</TD></TR>       
    <TR>

        <TD colspan="3">

        <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
        <tr>
        <td>
        <TABLE  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
            <c:if test="${homeActionForm.listOfOperation  != null }">
        <input type = "hidden" value="" name="selectedMainOperation">

            <c:forEach var="homeList" items="${homeActionForm.listOfOperation}">
<A href="javascript:fn_selectRadio('<c:out value="${homeList.optionkey}"/>')"       >
                <TR valign="top" class="datext2" >
                    <TD valign="top" colspan="3" align="left">

                            <INPUT type="radio"
                                name="arrival" id="${homeList.optionkey}"
                                value="${homeList.optionkey}" onclick="fn_onsel(this.value)" > 
                            <%--    <bean:message key="${homeList.optionValue}"/> --%>
            <a href="javascript:fn_selectRadio('<c:out value="${homeList.optionkey}"/>')" class="datext3"><bean:message key="${homeList.optionValue}"/></a>
                    </TD>


                </TR>
                </A>

            </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        <c:if test="${homeActionForm.listOfOperation  == null }">
            <TR valign="top" class="datext2" >
                <TD><bean:message key="lbl.arrival.handheldhome.noaccess"/><br><font color="red"><bean:message key="lbl.arrival.handheldhome.contactsysadmin"/></font></TD>
            </TR>
        </c:if>

        </TABLE>
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<input type="hidden" name="commandId" value=""/>

</html:form>
<!-- added in the bottom of body -->
 <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
            width: 93% !important;
            zoom: 175%;
             }
    }
    <style>

</BODY>

</html>
```

Pages should be responsive for the handheld devices which written in HTML 4.01.

Comment: Are you sure the software on the "two new tracking Handheld devices" support `<meta viewport>`?

Comment: Motorola MC67  OS :- Microsoft Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional
MOtorola TC77 OS :- Android 8.01 .. 
I guess these devices support meta view port. Kindly help me on how to check this @Quentin

Comment: Pointing it at a simple test document, consisting of valid HTML and some really obvious CSS like a background colour change based on the size would be a good start.

Comment: have tried applying the background-color using media query .. dint't work out.@Quentin

Comment: Then I guess the browser doesn't support it and the Doctype is irrelevant. (And this is why creating an [mcve] is important, it lets you narrow down the issue).

Comment: Your doctype is declaring XHTML. This is not HTML 4.01, you are in quirks mode,  and I am positive you are not serving as XHTML. Furthermore, your HTML uses many obsolete elements and attributes and, overall, seems to be thoroughly invalid.

Comment: Have copied HTML code whatever shown in the page since by removing any tags might be given incorrect solution from here. Anyhow removed script tags from the code and let me know what would be the solution for this scenario?

Comment: As I told, these were existing code and now have to make it responsive for the new devices. I have access to change the existing coed only if it affects for the responsive design @Rob

Comment: As I see, both HTML4.01 & XHTML Doctype are mentioned for IEversion 6 & 6.5. May I know the reason for the downvote since I have told you the codes are existing and asked for the solution for responsive page. @rob

Comment: If you are targeting IE6, all hope is lost as IE versions 9 and under do not support any responsive techniques and any ability to work with your markup makes this question far, far too broad.

Comment: My question is neither for IE6 nor for IE9.  is for the two handheld devices alone. Let known help me on resolving this problem. @Rob

Comment: How to make the browser should support for this code @Quentin

Comment: @passionFinder — Get the source code of the browser. Add the feature. Recompile the browser. Install it on the device.

Answer (score -2):

Replace your media query @media screen and (max-width: 767px) with this @media only screen and (max-width: 767)

Comment: `max-width: 767` is invalid CSS. What makes you think that introducing an error will solve the problem?